# Setting DHCP server in Linux centos

Tags: linux, centos-7, dhcp-server

I am using windows 8.1

I have just finished installing dhcp server. I type service dhcpd configtest, and responds; syntax ok

when type "service dhcpd start"

it responds by "starting dhcpd : [FAILED]

Answer (score 0):

centos 7 uses systemctl as its standard init system, so you should try systemctl start dhcpd instead.

Do not forget to allow incoming udp traffic on ports 67 and 68.

I usually test my dhcpd.conf with dhcpd -t, by the way.